# XCode workspace integrity - couldn't load project (pods.xcodepoj)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I pulled from git and everything works fine except I got this error even though I can still run the project. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: ``rm -rf “${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods”


rm -rf “`pwd`/Pods/”


pod update``

I did this to reinstall all pods and solved the issue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This usually means there was a merge conflict that got committed to the actual project.pbxproj file.

Since this is a Pods project (which is ephemeral and can be recreated at will) you can run `pod install` from the command line (in the same folder as your `Podfile` and it will regenerate the project.

Comment: hi, @Ben i'm also facing the same issue, tried your solution but still the issue is there.

Comment: @NikhilSawant if pod install works without error then you have something else going on with your xcproj files. Maybe do a diff with a previous version that is known to be working? (Diffing project files is no fun, but that's the only way to resolve this)

Comment: Sometimes just installing pods does not work. After installing pods (pod install), reopen the project after quiting XCode, it works.

Comment: @Vinod if that's happening then something is wrong with your setup. If you're not able to do a build after pod install, you should focus on getting that to work.

Answer (score 1):

problem:- Workspace integrity (could not load project) I got the same issue also I hit and try many solutions (Restart mac, Cache data remove, pods update, pods install, etc) but all in vain.

Solution : Once I try to open the project the "Xcode.copy" opened intead of my original Xcode . I just close all projects after that I open the project from selecting Xcode directly from the finder.

Note:- do not go to the project folder then open project from "projectName.xcworkspace"

you just need to go finder(Spotlite search) and open Xcode and open from finder then you must select the desired project. The project will work perfectly and after that you can open project manually (in your folder etc)
:) These things working from my side.